Как создавать элементы окна с рандомными названиями WPF
У меня есть сетка 20 на 10 (высота X ширина). Нужно создавать в этой сетке StackPanel (SP), но проблема в том, что их неограниченное количество, а значит, что их может быть как 10, так и 1,000,000,000. Поэтому нужен способ для создания SP по шаблону, через C#. Так же желательно найти такой способ, чтобы он поочередно брал не занятые числа, то есть: если я создам "StackPanel111" и удалю его, то программа сможет создать новый SP под названием "StackPanel111"  Единственный способ, который пришел в голову следующий:
Random rndm = new Random;
private void RandomNameSP (Random rndm)
{
StackPanel SP = new StackPanel
{
//здесь должен быть какой-то макет, но это не важно.
}
//И тут уже идет код по типу: "Какая-то переменная" = ""Какое-нибудь название по типу: SP" + {rndm.Next(0,1000000000)}";
}

Если что-то непонятно, можете уточнить, если буду знать, то смогу написать что да как.

А зачем собственно рандом, если требуется некая упорядоченная последовательность?  Для генерации нового номера (без удалений) достаточно использовать инкремент.  Если элементы будут удаляться, следует завести отсортированный сет, куда будут записываться "удалённые" числа.  Тогда при создании нового номера можно переиспользовать минимальный элемент из ранее удалённых, пока сет не станет пустым.

Вы совершенно не в том направлении думаете. WPF это не про создание кода через C#. Научитесь отделять данные от UI, научитесь делать основные вещи WPF, а именно привязки, научитесь использовать основной механизм создания UI - XAML. Вы не должны хотеть вообще использовать/создавать/изменять UI в C# коде (если только это не контрол). Так что, если у вас там условно 10 "Ивановых", которых надо вывести, то это не 10 StackPanel, а простая коллекция классов, привязанное к UI, где будет ItemsSource с нужным видом, все.

@EvgeniyZ У меня есть идея самому попробовать "топорно" написать тетрис хочу его сделать в нескольких режимах "20x10", "40x10", "80x10", а также со сложностью: "лёгкая", "средняя", "сложная" (тупо изначально макс и мин время падения/появления блока уменьшены, а так же увеличенно сокращение времени). Поэтому нужен такой "ущербный" способ. Так же было бы отлично, если бы, вы, писали более "простыми" словами, не очень то я в этих терминах разбираюсь:)

@Nowhere Man Этот вопрос перевернул всё моё понимание моего проекта в целом. Я только допёр, что если я создаю поле 20x10, то мне необходимо просто тупо создать 200 StackPanel(ну или что-то поудобнее), а также способ, который будет их убирать и очищать от изменений. В принципе моя проблема решена, но если есть способ менее "топорный", то я был бы рад его получить.

Не нужен вам такой "ущербный" способ. Привяжите массив один раз и работайте дальше просто с этим массивом, заполняя нужные ячейки нужными классами, все, вот весь ваш тетрис. Повторю, если вы не используете привязки и XAML в WPF, то вы выбрали не ту технологию, ибо вы не используете основные, ее отличительные от других преимущества. Вы сейчас пишете ваш проект так, как это делают в WinForms, вот берите тогда его) В любом случае, вы хозяин своего проекта, делайте как считаете нужным. Моя задача лишь предупредить и попробовать направить в нужное русло, не более.

@EvgeniyZ я про массивы в тетрисе видел у одного индуса (не в обиду если кого-то мог оскорбить) на ютубе, но чет он сложно там объясняет, будто его целевая аудитория прошаренные программисты. Если есть время, не могли бы, вы, написать как это можно сделать.

Я вам советую попробовать сделать свой проект в консоли, в виде простой сетки с крестиками, так вы поймете что такое матрицы, как с ними работать, и так далее. Если хотите пример на WPF, то вот вам пример змейки, который работает по аналогичному принципу, где есть поле из клеток и конкретным ячейкам задается нужное. Вот у вас должно быть тоже самое, только должны формироваться стандартные фигуры в матрице.

@EvgeniyZ. спасибо попробую разобраться по вашему совету в матрице
